# extracting word from a sentence using split in python

Tags: python

I am having difficulty in understanding as for how this piece of code works.

```
def get_title(name):
    if '.' in name:
        return name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()
    else:
        return 'Unknown'

ans=get_title('Braund, Mr. Owen Harris')
print (ans)
```

As I know the split is used for splitting characters but this does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to understand what happens if you play a little with with Python REPL. The most interesting part happens in line 3 of the code you've shown:

```
return name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()
```

Let's run it step by step in REPL to understand what happens:

```
>>> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')
['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']
>>> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')[1]
' Mr. Owen Harris'
>>> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')[1].split('.')
[' Mr', ' Owen Harris']
>>> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')[1].split('.')[0]
' Mr'
>>> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()
'Mr'
```

As you can see this function is meant to extract titles like `Mr`, `Ms` etc. This implementation is error prone if specific characters like `,` or `.` are not found in the input string, for example:

```
>>> 'Braund Mr. Owen Harris'.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the splits one by one and see how its going, for example:

```
name = 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'
name = name.split(',')[1] # this split will give ['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']
                          # then it takes element 1 which is ' Mr. Owen Harris'
name = name.split('.')[0] # here the split is [' Mr', ' Owen Harris']
                          # then it takes elemet 0 which is ' Mr'
name = name.strip()       # strip removes white spaces from the string (the leading space for this case)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is called [Method chaining](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). This means that if a method returns an object, you can append a method on the returned object directly on the calling method.

Let's break down that return line of code:

- `name.split(',')` returns a list of items, where each ',' in the string is treated as a separator between list items. On `'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris')`, this returns the following list: `['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']`
- The following `[1]` selects the second item in the list, which is a string object (`'Mr. Owen Harris'`)
- Next, `split('.')` splits that string again into a list, returning `['Mr', 'Owen Harris']`.
- Then, the first item is selected by `[0]`, returning the string `'Mr'`.
- Finally, `strip()` removes all whitespaces from the beginning and the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You start with:

```
'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'
```

The first `split` will find all ',' and split the string at those positions. So you get:

```
['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']
```

Then you take the second element so you are left with:

```
' Mr. Owen Harris'
```

You then split this string by '.' and get:

```
[' Mr', ' Owen Harris']
```

After that you take the first element:

```
' Mr'
```

And strip it:

```
'Mr'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain based on your example:

```
name = 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'

if '.' in name:
```

Does name contain `.`? Yes, then you split name using `,`, which returns:

```
['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']
```

Now, you retrieve the second element (`name.split(',')[1]`), and you split it using `.`, which returns:

```
[' Mr', ' Owen Harris']
```

Then, you retrieve the first element (`name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0]`), which returns:

```
' Mr'
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)is used to remove extra leading and trailing spaces.

Then the final result:

```
'Mr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
    def get_title(name):
        print type(name), name 
        if '.' in name:
            print  type(name.split(',')), name.split(',') 
            print  type(name.split(',')[1]) , name.split(',')[1]  
            print  type(name.split(',')[1].split('.')  ), name.split(',')[1].split('.')        
            print  type(name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0])  , name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0]                  
            print  type(name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip() ), name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()    
            return name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()
        else:
            return 'Unknown'

    ans=get_title('Braund, Mr. Owen Harris')
    print (ans)
```

Returns:

```
<type 'str'> Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
<type 'list'> ['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris']
<type 'str'>  Mr. Owen Harris
<type 'list'> [' Mr', ' Owen Harris']
<type 'str'>  Mr
<type 'str'> Mr
Mr
```